# How to call https.request again when it is failed using setTimeout

Tags: node.js, https, settimeout

I am using https.request in node for sending an object and waiting for response, if it fails I'm using set timeout to call the function again after 50 seconds, code is something like this :-

```
function post(){
 var options = {
     hostname: 'something.google.com',
     port: 443,
     path: '/',
     method: 'post'
 };

 var data = {.....}

 var req = https.request(options,(res)=>{
 ....
 ...
 });

 req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
 req.on('error',(e)=>{
    setTimeout(()=> {
       post();
    ​}, 50000);
  })
 req.end();
}
```

Is it a good way of calling the function using setTimeout in error?
Is there another way of calling the function again if it fails using http server.setTimeout or anything else ?

Comment: if it fails , it will keep calling it until success. better to have number of tries to make if fails.

Comment: I am looking to call it until success. The objects (options and data) will be updated frequently, so somewhere it will get connected.

Comment: If the data really get updated so frequently, then probably you'll want to implement the solution using socket instead

Comment: can you please provide an example for that ?